# "The specified procedure could not be found" error with .NET 4

Tags: .net, dllimport, dll

I am developing on a 64-bit Windows 7 box with Visual Studio 2012 (11.0.51106.01 Update 1).

I have a Support project that compiles some C code into a (32-bit) DLL. In my header I have:

```
#define RET_TYPE(type) _declspec(dllexport) type __stdcall

RET_TYPE(int) test_dll_call(int invar);
```

In my C file I have:

```
RET_TYPE(int) test_dll_call(int invar)
{
   int retVal = 4 * invar;

   return retVal;
}
```

I also have a (32-bit) WPF C# application that loads the DLL inside of a class as follows:

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, BestFitMapping = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
public static extern int test_dll_call(int invar);
```

This is wrapped as follows:

```
public void Wrap_TestDllCall()
{
   try
   {
      int outTest = 0;
      int invar = 3;

      outTest = test_dll_call(invar);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      dllError = ex.ToString();
   }
}
```

When I run this in the debugger on my development box, this works fine. If I copy all the relevant files to a separate folder and run it from there, it works fine.

If I copy all the necessary folders to another computer running 32-bit Windows XP SP3 I get the following error:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'MyDll.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)
   at MyNamespace.MyClass.test_dll_call(Int32 invar)
   at MyNamespace.MyClass.Wrap_TestDllCall()
```

I have used dependency walker on both my compiled exe and the dll; the only missing dlls it found were `wer.dll` and `ieshims.dll`, which from my research are not needed on XP.

I have installed the VS2012 C++ Redistributable, and .NET 4, and the .NET 4.0.3 update. Still no luck.

**Edit** As Hans points out, this *appears* to be that the app can't find the procedure in the DLL; I have also tried:

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int test_dll_call(int invar);
```

and

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl test_dll_call(int invar);
```

Which also works fine on my dev box but gives the same error on the WinXP box.

Help!

Comment: It is not complaining about a missing DLL, it cannot find the "test_dll_call" function in the DLL.  Very few ways that can go wrong, other than having copied the wrong DLL.

Comment: Okay, so what are those other ways? It works on my dev box but not on my WinXP test laptop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved. Some things to note as I went through troubleshooting steps, for those who stumble upon this in the future.

1. This error does not necessarily mean it can't find procedure `X` -- rather it may mean it can't find function `Y`, from another dll, that is called by `X`.
2. Make sure to compile the DLL in 'Release' mode, as the C++ redistributable will not include the debug DLLs.
3. Start with a shell function, and add pieces back in, one by one.

In my above test example, the problem was I was compiling as a Debug version.

However, in my complete function, that change did not fix the issue. It turns out I was missing some DLLs that dependency walker did not catch.