# Unable to load DLL 'myDLL.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dll, dllimport

I have WCF service that call to function "init" from some dllwrapper.dll.
When i call dllwrapper.init, i got the exception:

```
Unable to load DLL 'myDLL.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)
```

when dllwrapper.dll try to import myDLL.dll.
It happend to me only with WCF services. other service (console app) that call dllwrapper.init, dont get this exception.
what can be the problem here?
thanks

Comment: It's really hard to tell without seeing your specific project and dependencies. Here's, however, a good write-up which might point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904080/the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found-error-with-net-4

Comment: That's ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND. Pretty simple. Call to GetProcAddress fails because the function name is not one of the exports. What more can we say?

Comment: Use Process Monitor to figure out where it loads the DLL from and compare that to the where the Console application loads the DLL from